# How to route a jenkins job to any available Node/slave when node selection plugin too present in job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Assume I have multiple nodes/slaves (Say 5 nodes) configured to my jenkins master.. 
Assume I have a job which i usually trigger manually...and I have configured this job to have 'Node label parameter plugin'...
so while I trigger the job I can choose any node from the list ,and then the job will be built in that respective node I chosen. this is fine..

I do not want this to happen always... that means I want to choose the node only when I wish...and most of the other times Jenkins should route the job to any available/free node.

Having Node label parameter plugin configured to the job, will force me to choose any single node....
I would like to see something like a blank value as a default one in the node parameter, so in that case it can route the job to any node which is free.... this plugin do not give a blank value ,also not selecting any node from multi-select dropdown looks not effective, it will route the job to first node in the list.

any solution / workaround for this use-case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine all the nodes in a single group. Then, in the job you can select that group name instead of node name. So that Jenkins job automatically find the available node with in that group to build the solution.

**Process to group the nodes:**
Go to node configuration and add the group name in the "Label" section. update all node configurations similarly with the same Label name. So that all these comes under single group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the above is the better one . Figured out this little later.. the add parameters section will provide you a parameter of type 'Label'
You can have a default value for this label..

The default value can be something like 'anyNode'
'anyNode' should be added a label to all your available nodes...
In adition to the above label, each node can also have there on specific label... like machin1,machin2 etc...

The Label parameter in the job can take input from user while triigering the job
By default it is 'anyNode', but user can override this to any as 'machin1', 2 etc...